# Macro doesn't work in the function

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I have problems with following code: http://lisper.ru/apps/format/96

The problem is in "normalize" function, which does not work.
It fails on the fifth line: `(zero-p a indexes i)`

```
(defun normalize (a &optional indexes i)
  "Returns normalized A."
  (progn
   (format t "Data=~A ~A ~A" a indexes i)
   (if (zero-p a indexes i)
      a ;; cannot normalize empty vector
    (let* ((mmm (format t "Zero?=~a" (zero-p a indexes i)))
             (L (sqrt (+ (do-op-on * a :x a :x indexes i indexes i)
                         (do-op-on * a :y a :y indexes i indexes i)
                         (do-op-on * a :z a :z indexes i indexes i))))
             (mmm (format t "L=~a" L))
             (L (/ 1D0 L))
             (mmm (format t "L=~a" L))) ; L=1/length(A)
      (make-V3 (* (ref-of a :x indexes i) l)
                 (* (ref-of a :y indexes i) l)
                 (* (ref-of a :z indexes i) l))))))
```

in function "normalize" I call the macro "zero-p", which in turn calls macro "ref-of", which is the last in the chain.

```
(defmacro zero-p (v &optional indexes index)
  "Checks if the vector is 'almost' zero length."
  `(and (< (ref-of ,v :x ,indexes ,index) *min+*)
 (< (ref-of ,v :y ,indexes ,index) *min+*)
 (< (ref-of ,v :z ,indexes ,index) *min+*)
 (> (ref-of ,v :x ,indexes ,index) *min-*)
 (> (ref-of ,v :y ,indexes ,index) *min-*)
 (> (ref-of ,v :z ,indexes ,index) *min-*)))
```

Here is ref-of:

```
(defmacro ref-of (values coordinate &optional indexes index)
  "Please see DATA STRUCTURE for details."
  (if indexes
    (cond ((eq coordinate :x) `(aref ,values (aref ,indexes ,index)))
   ((eq coordinate :y) `(aref ,values (+ 1 (aref ,indexes ,index))))
   ((eq coordinate :z) `(aref ,values (+ 2 (aref ,indexes ,index))))
   (T (error "The symbol ~S is not :X, :Y or :Z." coordinate)))
    (cond ((eq coordinate :x) `(aref ,values 0))
 ((eq coordinate :y) `(aref ,values 1))
     ((eq coordinate :z) `(aref ,values 2))
     (T (error "The symbol ~S is not :X, :Y or :Z." coordinate)))))
```

Also, in "normalize" I call the macro "do-op-on", which calls "ref-of" as well.

```
(defmacro do-op-on (op name1 coord1 name2 coord2 &optional is1 i1 is2 i2)
  "Example: (do-op-on * A :x B :y i n) == A[i[n]].x*B.y"
  `(,op (ref-of ,name1 ,coord1 ,is1 ,i1) (ref-of ,name2 ,coord2 ,is2 ,i2)))
```

As a result, instead of having this: `(aref some-array 0)` I have `(aref NIL NIL)` which is created in "ref-of".

I suppose that I lose the symbol A from the call `(normalize A)`. I just feel that the symbol does not survive the macroexpanson. The thing is, macroexpansoin works in REPL for each macro independently.

Can anyone explain where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive than "does not work"? Which macro is it that doesn't work? Imagine you are a bug reporter.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!  
I clarified the question.

Comment: What language (Common Lisp?) and implementation are you using?

Comment: @Svante: I want no function calls. Why should I?

Comment: @Chris: at the moment ccl-1.4 (Clozure CL)

Comment: @avp:  to make the code comprehensible (but I think this has now been answered in Pillsy's answer).  From your comment "see the DATA STRUCTURE", I have the impression that you could reduce your code complexity a lot by using CLOS (see the hyperspec for `defclass`, `defgeneric` and `defmethod`, and the chapter "Object reorientation" in the free book "Practical Common Lisp").  Your `ref-of` and `do-op-on` would likely just disappear, or be reduced to a simple declaration in a `defclass` form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the macros `ZERO-P` and `REF-OF` are expanded when you evaluate, compile or load the `DEFUN` for `NORMALIZE`. Their arguments are the *symbols* `INDEXES` and `INDEX`, and both of those are not `NIL`, so the `IF`s in the `REF-OF` forms will all take the first branch and expand into `AREF` forms where `INDICES` and `INDEX` can't be bound to `NIL`. In short, you've gotten evaluation time and macroexpansion time confused, which is an easy thing to do when you are just starting with macros.

However, when you call the function `NORMALIZE` with only one argument, the variables `INDICES` and `INDEX` are bound to a default value of `NIL`, so `AREF` complains that it's getting invalid arguments.

The best solution I can offer you is to just make `ZERO-P` and `REF-OF` into functions instead of macros. They'll work just fine as functions, and you shouldn't make something a macro unless you're sure it needs to be a macro. If you really do want to keep them as macros, give default values to `INDICES` and `INDEX` that make sense and get rid of the optional values in `REF-OF` and `ZERO-P`---I'm pretty sure having `INDEX` default to 0 and `INDICES` default to `#(0 1 2)` will work.

**EDIT to add:** Wanting to avoid function call overhead is almost certainly not a good reason to use macros in Lisp. In the first place, you shouldn't even worry about function call overhead until after you've done some profiling and testing. In the second place, if you do have a problem with function call overhead, you should `DECLARE` the functions in question `INLINE` instead of using macros to do the inlining.

**EDITed** again to add: If your functions are being expanded inline, your compiler should be able to figure out that it can replace

```
(cond ((eq :x :x) 'foo)
      ((eq :x :y) 'bar)
      ((eq :x :z) 'quux)
      (t (error "~A is not one of :X, :Y or :Z" :x))
```

with

```
'foo
```

Comment: PRAGMA was a misprint at the last moment. PROGN.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I just want to clarify one thing.
You've said: "...shouldn't make something a macro unless you're sure...". So how can I be sure? I introduced macros to simplify the code, not to add any functions to the library... Is this reason good enough?

Comment: No, if you just want to simplify your code, always see if you can factor things into smaller functions first. Functions are simpler than macros---they're easier to test, they can be traced, and they show up in debugger backtraces. They can also be used directly with functions like `MAPCAR`, `REDUCE` or `EVERY`.

Answer (score 1):

What is `PRAGMA`? It is not standard. Maybe you mean [`PROGN`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progn.htm) (which is not even necessary since `DEFUN` supplies an implicit `PROGN`)?

Why all the macros? Is there some reason to disallow a form like `(reduce (lambda (r c) (* (ref-of A c) r)) (list :x :y :z) :initial-value 1)`? This seems like a case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Pillsy's answer is right on: when `REF-OF` is expanded (from the usage of `ZERO-P`), its `INDEXES` will have the symbol `INDEXES` as its value, not the value passed into `NORMALIZE` (like wise `INDEX` will be `I`).

Comment: You are right, I confused the word. I added it at the last moment for debugging. Fixed.

Comment: About macros: how can I be sure that the code would be executed in compile-time otherwise?

Comment: Yes, '(reduce (lambda (c) (ref-of A c)) (list :x :y :z) :initial-value 1)' is good idea, thanks.